# ASP.NET MVC 401 error invalid credentials for non-local login

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I receive a 401 error (invalid credentials) when I login over the Internet. 
This happens only for some users on a deployed system. These users are
added during the Identity database initialization.

If I login locally on the deployment server, the login works fine. Additionally,
I have no problems when logging in locally on my development computer.

The authentification is based on the Identity framework.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Too little information to know what the matter is

Comment: Regarding the code, the web page for which the 401 error is shown, is protected with an Authorize for a specific role. I tried to redirect to a page without an Authorize but still the same error is shown.

Comment: I checked also the database entries of the Identity framework, but the only difference is that the LockoutEnabled flag is not set for all users for which the login fails. If I change this value, login still fails.

Comment: A collegue found something: If the user, for which the login failed, is added to a role, for which the login succeeded, the login will then succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem is that in the header of the page an action was called, for which the users whose login failed had no authorization. It is strange that it worked for local logins.